# GetPrivateProfileString() returns empty string, despite having a default

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

```
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias _
        "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
            ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
            ByVal lpDefault As String, _
            ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
            ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
```

```
Dim value As String = ""
Dim length As Integer
Dim IniFileName As String

GetPrivateProfileString("Config", "UserName", "None", value, length, IniFileName)
```

but `value` contains an empty string!?

I confes to being a VB n00b, less than a week, in fact, but I can't see what's wrong there. The file exists, it contains a section called "Config" which has an entry called "UserName" with a value - but even if not, wouldn't `value` take the default?

(And, no, I don't want to use the registry, thanks ;-)

---

Edit:  It's not returning an empty string - it's returning whatever I initialize `value` to before calling `GetPrivateProfileString()`.

Which is to say that if I

```
Dim value As String = "xxx"
```

then it stil contains "xxx" after the call and not the default value.

Comment: I tried to push the function declaration into the code-block, but for some reason it's having none of it - just incase you wondered why I'd edited your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the size in the params, and reserve space for the result.
Insert this lines before the call to the function:

```
value = space(255)
length = len(value)
```

Forgot something: you have to use the return value of the function, as this is the length of the actual value you get, and use a `Left(value,length)` to get your real answer.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure codepage of your INI-file is ANSI.
I was getting empty results because my ini was in UTF-8.

Was not obvious for me.

Comment: I created an ini file in Visual Studio. It put 3 bytes at the beginning of the file that completely broke this function. Took me 45 minutes to figure it out. After looking at the file in HexEdit (and seeing this comment above) I delete the file and re-created it in Sublime Text. Worked perfectly. Don't use the VS text editor!

Comment: This took a while to find! Thank you very much you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `length` and `value` as following:

```
Dim length As Integer = 255
Dim value As String = New String(" "c, length)
```

Also, according the code you posted, `IniFileName` seems empty. Maybe you need to assign a value there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example at [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileString.htm), the signature you're using for calling GetPrivateProfileString isn't quite right. Specifically, the signature shown at PInvoke.net passes through a StringBuilder and the size of the stringbuilder.

In your example, you're passing through an empty string and a zero length, so the call to GetPrivateProfileString will only ever return an empty (zero length) string, because you're telling it that the the output buffer (value) you're passing in is suitable for a zero length string.

To get the result you're expecting, your code therefore needs to be:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    Private Declare Auto Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpAppName As String, _
                ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
                ByVal lpDefault As String, _
                ByVal lpReturnedString As StringBuilder, _
                ByVal nSize As Integer, _
                ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer

    Sub Main()
        Dim value as String
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim sb As StringBuilder
        Dim IniFileName As String = "PathAndFilenameGoesHere"

        sb = New StringBuilder(300)
        result = GetPrivateProfileString("Config", "UserName", "", sb, sb.Capacity,IniFileName)
        value = sb.ToString()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: -1: I stared using the pinvoke signature, then switched to the OP signature which requires less code and works without problems

Comment: This is literally the best way to do this.  Shame it's not marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

FYI:

You also get an empty string if your default is "" and you provide a filename that doesn't exist, or provide a filename without the full path. GetPrivateProfileString() doesn't return an error if it can't find the source file and just uses the default.